# Loopback 4 authentication metadata options undefined

Tags: node.js, loopback

I have created a simple jwt auth application the same way its displayed here: https://github.com/raymondfeng/loopback4-example-auth0

The authentication part is working properly but the authorization does not work as expected.

I decorated my controller with following function and added a scope.

```
@authenticate({strategy: 'auth0-jwt', options: {scopes: ['greet']}})
```

In my authentication strategy I´m checking the scope via the AuthenticationMetadata class.

```
import {AuthenticationBindings, AuthenticationMetadata, AuthenticationStrategy} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {ExpressRequestHandler, Request, Response, RestBindings} from '@loopback/rest';
import {UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
import {JWT_SERVICE} from './types';

const jwtAuthz = require('express-jwt-authz');

export class JWTAuthenticationStrategy implements AuthenticationStrategy {
  name = 'auth0-jwt';

  constructor(
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE)
    private response: Response,
    @inject(AuthenticationBindings.METADATA)
    private metadata: AuthenticationMetadata,
    @inject(JWT_SERVICE)
    private jwtCheck: ExpressRequestHandler,
  ) {}

  async authenticate(request: Request): Promise<UserProfile | undefined> {
    return new Promise<UserProfile | undefined>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.jwtCheck(request, this.response, (err: unknown) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(this.metadata.options);
        // If the `@authenticate` requires `scopes` check
        if (this.metadata.options?.scopes) {
          jwtAuthz(this.metadata.options!.scopes, {failWithError: true})(request, this.response, (err2?: Error) => {
            if (err2) {
              console.error(err2);
              reject(err2);
              return;
            }
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
            resolve((request as any).user);
          });
        } else {
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
          resolve((request as any).user);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

When trying to access

```
this.metadata.options
```

I´m always getting an undefined back.

How can I achieve to get the options and the scope out of metadata?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Loopback Authorization your class needs to implement the `Provider<Authorizer>` interface. In that interface it defines the 2 functions you need to implement

```
@injectable({scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT})
class AuthorizationService implements Provider<Authorizer>{

  value (): Authorizer {
    return this.authorize.bind(this);  
  }

  async authorize (
    context: AuthorizationContext,
    metadata: AuthorizationMetadata,
  ) {
     // TODO implement authorization
  }

}
```

The authorization metadata will be injected by loopback into that function automatically after you bind it with an `AuthorizationTags.Authorizer`

If you are having problems implementing `Authentication` then read my [step by step guide](https://dev.to/alfonsojohan/loopback-4-jwt-authentication-with-firebase-1o4) on how we implemented Loopback Authentication using Firebase. That should be able to help you with the core ideas to get `Authentication` running.